# to import certain cells in the column in Excel to C #

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

My excel file is that column1A: city,ankara,ankara,ankara,istanbul,istanbul,izmir
I want to that combobox looks like ankara,istanbul,izmir
it doesn't again.

```
OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");    
baglan.Open();    
string sql = "Select * From [Sayfa1$A1:A100] ";    
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);    
OleDbDataReader dr = null;    
dr = komut.ExecuteReader();    
while (dr.Read())
{    
   if (dr[0] != "")
   {    
        combobox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());    
   }    
   else    
   {    
       break;   
   }    
}   
baglan.Close();
```

Comment: Please try to explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Do you wanna add only distinct values?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (dr[0] != ""){   

   if(!combobox1.Items.Contains(dr[0])){

    combobox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");    
baglan.Open();    
string sql = "Select * From [Sayfa1$A1:A100] ";    
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);    
OleDbDataReader dr = null;    
dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
     // To Copy distinct values from specified column to a different datatable
    DataTable diffValues = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColName");
    combobox1.DataSource = datatable;
```

It works for me.